# Consulta SQL onde os 2 últimos algarismos do WHERE devem ser ignorados

Tags: sql, select, where, db2

Vou tentar ir direto ao ponto.

Tenho o seguinte `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM "Inverter" WHERE "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C023900-15-0B4B00' AND "CreatedTime_Key" > 20170718000000 AND "CreatedTime_Key" <= 20170718001500 AND "DataQuality" = 1 ORDER BY "CreatedTime_Key" ASC
```

Queria saber se tem algum comando que faça o `WHERE` ignorar os 2 últimos algarismos do valor que estou comparando com ele. Exemplo:

```
"CreatedTime_Key" > 201707180000(00) AND "CreatedTime_Key" <= 201707180015(00)
```

> Números entre '()' são os que quero ignorar.

Exemplos para melhor entendimento do que quero fazer:

Exemplo da tabela:

```
| ID | CreatedTime_Key |  Nome  |
| 01 | 20170718000001  |  CAIO  |
| 02 | 20170718000501  |  JOAO  |
| 03 | 20170718000002  |  MARIA |
| 04 | 20170718001000  |  MARIO |
...
```

Quero que o `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM "Inverter" WHERE "InstallationUUID" = '0D013C023900-15-0B4B00' AND "CreatedTime_Key" > 20170718000000 AND "CreatedTime_Key" <= 20170718001500 AND "DataQuality" = 1 ORDER BY "CreatedTime_Key" ASC
```

Me retorne:

```
| ID | CreatedTime_Key |  Nome  |
| 02 | 20170718000501  |  JOAO  |
| 04 | 20170718001000  |  MARIO |
```

> OBS: Não posso mudar os valores que vão no `WHERE`. Eles precisam ser
>   dessa forma de DateTime (20170818001500 = 2017/07/18 00:15:00), ou
>   seja preciso ignorar os segundos no `WHERE`.

Comment: Qual o seu `SGBD`?

Comment: @Sorack IBM DB2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possibilidade que você pode utilizar e usar aq função LEFT, informando quantos caracteres você que utilizar a partir da esquerda, é interessante considerar se o tamanho do dado será o mesmo para todos os registros.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Inverter
WHERE InstallationUUID = '0D013C023900-15-0B4B00'
AND LEFT(CreatedTime_Key, 12) > 201707180000
AND LEFT(CreatedTime_Key, 12) <= 201707180015
AND DataQuality = 1
ORDER BY CreatedTime_Key ASC
```

Comment: por acaso o comando `left` só funciona com string? Pois testei aqui e não me retornou nenhum valor. A coluna seria do tipo `BIGINT`, atualizei a pergunta informando o tipo.

Comment: Executa a script abaixo pra ver os valores que é apresentado: SELECT  *,  LEFT(CreatedTime_Key, 12) FROM Inverter
WHERE InstallationUUID = '0D013C023900-15-0B4B00'

Comment: ele traz a coluna `CreatedTime_Key` cortada certinha, sem os 2 últimos valores.

Comment: Atualizei a query de resposta, dá uma verificada se está trazendo o que esperava!!

Comment: Não basta apenas pegar o resultado da divisão de seu bigint por 100 para fazer a comparação?

Comment: @Oliveira era justamente o valor de comparação que estava errado(você editou), precisa botar sem os 2 últimos dígitos também. Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!